# Pass numpy array as function argument

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to pass a numpy array `arr` to `what_a_function` and print the resulting array, and this should be done without using loop. I know it is ugly and unfriendly, but I have to do so. I tried with `vectorize` but kept failing. May anyone share some pointers please? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
def what_a_function(x):
    return -np.cos(x.all()) * (0.5 < np.sin(x) < 2) + (np.sin(x) <= 0.5) + (x ** 2) * (np.sin(x) >= 2)

a=1
b=5

vfunc = np.vectorize(what_a_function)
arr = np.arange(a,b+0.1,0.1)

print(arr)
print(vfunc(arr))
```

And it will complain `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'`.

Comment: Please show an example input and output. Also, `vectorize` is basically just a convenience method that isn't going to be faster than a `for` loop. Since the code fails, it's not clear to me what `x.all()` was intended to do.

Comment: Why are you using vectorize?

Comment: The point of `vectorize` is to take a function that only works on one value at a time (e.g., a float) and turn it into a function that takes an array of values and automatically loops over them. That means your code should be expecting `x` to be a float, and using float methods on it, not NumPy array methods. Or, better, it _should_ be using array methods, so you don’t need to use `vectorize` in the first place.

Comment: `vectorize` pass scalar elements of `arr` to `what_a_function`.  Thus `what_a_function` must work with a simple numeric `x`.

Comment: Thanks for all your reponse! I discovered later that it is because I forgot to remove `x.all()`. Sorry!

Comment: @roganjoshIn the example above, input is `a=1` and `b=5`, expected output is an array of floats computed by `what_a_function`, however, the interpreter was complaining about `x.all()` at that time. Now it is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That ' super ugly and unfriendly' equation doesn't make sense.  What kind of `x` value is it supposed to evaluate?

```
-np.cos(x.all()) * (0.5 < np.sin(x) < 2) + (np.sin(x) <= 0.5) + (x ** 2) * (np.sin(x) >= 2)
```

`x.all()` requires an array (with `all` method), and returns a boolean (scalar or array), which is a nonsense input for `np.cos`.

`np.sin(x)` is ok with a scalar or array, but the `0.5<...<2` only works for a scalar (it's Python that doesn't work for numpy).

The next `np.sin(x)<=.5` will produces a boolean (scalar or array).  `x**2` will be a numeric value.

The `+` and `*` will sort of work, converting the boolean True/False to 1/0 integers.  But logical operators are better.

If we knew what is was supposed to do, we could probably write it to work directly with a numeric array.  `np.vectorize` is not a good substitute for writing proper array compatible code.  As I commented, `vectorize` passes the array values to the function one by one, as scalars.  That's why the `all` method produces an error (and doesn't make sense). On top of that `vectorize` is slow.

A straight forward list comprehension is faster:

```
np.array([your_function(i) for i in x])
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear and concise answer! It's later discovered that `x,all()` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The function all() takes list as its argument. 
I made a tiny change to the code. I hope it helps!

```
import numpy as np
def what_a_function(x):
    return all([-np.cos(x)]) * (0.5 < np.sin(x) < 2) + (np.sin(x) <= 0.5) + (x ** 2) * (np.sin(x) >= 2)

a=1
b=5

vfunc = np.vectorize(what_a_function)
arr = np.arange(a, b+0.1, 0.1)

print(arr)
print(vfunc(arr))

Output:[1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.  2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7
2.8 2.9 3.  3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 3.7 3.8 3.9 4.  4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5
4.6 4.7 4.8 4.9 5. ]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```